# How does fulltext solr search really work with sunspot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

Ok in my Style model I've got things setup like this

```
  searchable do
    text :full_name
  end
```

However when I run

```
Style.search { fulltext 'Monkey' }.results
```

I get an empty result set. When I run the same search with

```
Style.search { fulltext 'Monkey Patch' }.results
```

I get the expected result. I was under the impression that the fulltext search would give you a result even if only a single word matched?

```
1.9.3p392 :002 > Style.first.full_name
  Style Load (3.0ms)  SELECT "styles".* FROM "styles" LIMIT 1
 => "Monkey Patch"
```

**EDIT**

This is my schema.xml file

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

[Full schema.xml file](https://gist.github.com/funkdified/5544471)

Comment: It depends on how your solrconfig.xml and schema.xml are setup. I don't know enough about how those work to opine meaningfully. I will say that when I search 'Monkey' I get the result.

Comment: I've put up my schema.xml file .. which is unmodified

Comment: If I copy in that file on my laptop, it works the way you would like it to :/